# TypeError: message.guild.member is not a function when trying to ban user

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am using the discord.js v12 library for my Discord bot, and overnight when I want to ban a user I got this error:

```
TypeError: message.guild.member is not a function
```

In the `constants.js` file I have included all my commands with different parameters. I also have another `message.js` file which looks at it if a command is typed and before executing it checks according to the parameters of the command if it is good or not, so I have for my `ban.js` command that if the user mentioned to the permission `BAN_MEMBERS` then we do not use the command on them.

Here is my code for this check and even after checking everything well on the discord.js documentation, I don't understand why it gives me an error:

```
if (command.help.isUserAdmin && message.guild.member(user).hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')) {
    return message.reply("you cannot use this command on this user.");
}
```

Comment: As per other examples I've seen, you may need to use a getter method there, `message.guild.member.get(user)`

Comment: Probably `message.guild` does not contain the property `member` for some reason. If that's the case `message.guild.member` is undefined, and if you try to do `undefiend()` you get an error. Do ALL messages have a guild without exception?

Comment: This could only happen if: a) `message.guild` is undefined, if this is a DM message; or b) `message` is undefined, because you did not pass in a `message` argument to whatever function your code is executing in.

Comment: If I use the method `message.guild.member.get(user)` it returns me `Cannot read property 'get' of undefined` I think it's normal because on the documentation we can't get the user of a guild like this, as far as private messages are concerned, it does not come from because the bot ignores them `if (message.channel.type === "dm") return client.emit("directMessage", message); `, my message and well defined yet? `module.exports = async (client, message) => { // code };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to fix the problem:

`message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).ban({days: 0, reason: reason})`

I learned that users' collections are mapped by their ids, so just grab and ban the mentioned user.

Comment: Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

`member` is not a property of the `guild` object therefore it is returning `undefined`. I assume you are trying to get the member who sent the message, so your code snippet can be written as:

```
if (command.help.isUserAdmin && message.member.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')) {
    return message.reply("you cannot use this command on this user.");
}
```

You can read more about using the Discord API [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome).

Comment: This does not work because `message.member` returns the user who sent the command, not the one mentioned: `const user = message.mentions.users.first();`, I have checked and the syntax correct is this one: `message.guild.member(user).hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')`, because in the `guild` collection, `member()` does indeed return the guild user using the Discord user. I don't understand why it doesn't work?

Comment: Where is `user` defined?

Comment: Before the condition, I gave the code just above.

Comment: I tried fetching user from cache and it seems to work: `message.guild.members.cache.get(user).hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')`, now I have another problem : `Cannot read property 'hasPermission' of undefined`, I think it returns this to me because it is probably undefined, yet I have done all the checks before but it still does not work.